# I used regex to remove all extra white space in my string, but when it executes, it removes extra white spaces but leaves 1 space at the end

Tags: c#, regex, whitespace

My question already states my problem.. So how do I properly remove all extra white space in a string?

Imagine the dashes are spaces.

my string = "[-----------na----me-----]"

output = "name-" (there is a space in the end of the string)

I used this code in a Leave event.

```
((Control)sender).Text = Regex.Replace(((Control)sender).Text, @"\s+", " ");
((Control)sender).Text.TrimEnd(' ');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be overthinking this.

Have you considered using the string Replace method.

For example:

```
    string s = "[       na    me      ]";
    var s2 = s.Replace(" ", "");
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Comment: getting +1  - last I saw for performance `String.Replace` blows the pants off `Regex.Replace`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a typo. Your main problem seems to be in your call to `Regex.Replace`. Look at the line very carefully: `" "` means to replace sequences of spaces with one single space. Try changing `" "` to `""`.

Also, the `((Control)sender).Text.TrimEnd(' ');` returns a new string and never updates `((Control)sender).Text`. Perhaps you meant to assign the result to `Text` again? Remember that in C# strings are immutable. However, by changing `" "` to `""`, you should not need that line anymore.

**Note**: This answer is based off of the example code. However, the example string and output do not match the example code.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into whitespace which is the `\r\n` so use this pattern instead: `[\s\r\n]+` to get all whitespace as well as any carriage return and line feeds. Also to be concise use `string.empty` instead of `""` as the replacement text.